# No Persistence provider for EntityManager named itmd4515PU

Tags: java, xml, maven, jpa

I'm new to JPA. 
I keep getting this error:

```
No Persistence provider for EntityManager named
```

I tried some suggestions from other posts. like adding

```
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
```

in Persistence.xml. and add

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

in the Pom.xml. I still got the same error.

[Error Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ceH1I.png)

Below is my Persistence Unit:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence     http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="itmd4515PU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/itmd4515DS</jta-data-source>
    <class>edu.iit.sat.itmd4515.jwang206.domain.Address</class>
    <class>edu.iit.sat.itmd4515.jwang206.domain.CD_Store</class>
    <class>edu.iit.sat.itmd4515.jwang206.domain.Item</class>
    <class>edu.iit.sat.itmd4515.jwang206.domain.Supplier</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
       <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action"     value="drop-and-create"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

and Pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>edu.iit.sat.itmd4515.jwang206</groupId>
<artifactId>jwang206-fp</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>jwang206-fp</name>

<properties>
    <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>

    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.5</version>

    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.0.CR1</version>

    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.el</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.6</version>

    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen.processor</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>





</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
                <compilerArguments>
                    <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                </compilerArguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                        <silent>true</silent>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                <version>7.0</version>
                                <type>jar</type>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

and my file structure:

[File hierarchy image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/scw35.png)

Please advise, Thanks very much !!

Answer (score 0):

You have got the API dependency which consists of javax.persistence interfaces but you also need some concrete implementations.

Add this dependency to you pom.xml (version number is up to you):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.7.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Then change the persistence provider to:

```
<persistence-unit name="itmd4515PU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
```

Comment: I'm still getting errors saying : Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to locate persistence units after I added the new implementation.

Comment: add the strucuture of the WAR file content.. especially where the META-INF is located

Comment: I'm sorry, but what do you mean add the structure of the WAR file content?

Comment: The persistence.xml has to be in /META-INF being at the root of the package. Is it?

Comment: any luck with the testing?